# display results with a show more link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to figure out a way to always show 5 jobs in my Rails app and then have a link that when clicked will show all of the remaining jobs.  Should I do something in my jobs_controller where I'm just getting the first 5 and then getting the rest, or is it better to do it in the view somehow?

```
<!-- company -->  
<div class="vertical-space">
    <b>Company Name</b><br />
  <div class="sub-text">

    <% Job.by_company_count.size.each do |name, count| %>
      <div class="indent"><%= link_to name, filtered_jobs_path(company: name) %>
      (<%= count %>)
      <br>
    </div><!--./indent-->
    <% end %>
  </div><!--./sub-text-->
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot call `each` method in result returned by `size` method, since `size` returns an *Integer*. See my answer below for a way of passing data to view.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to the view, set an instance variable of the controller, in the corresponding action:

`@jobs = Job.by_company_count`

And then access and iterate `@jobs` in view:

```
<% @jobs.each do |name, count| %>
  <div class="indent"><%= link_to name, filtered_jobs_path(company: name) %>
  (<%= count %>)
  <br>
</div><!--./indent-->
```

I'm assuming that you have a scope `by_company_count` defined in `Job` model!

Comment: the by_company_count gets a count of how many jobs there are per company, the view displays the the company name and the number of jobs next to it, it's working fine.  I'm trying to find how to only display a certain number of jobs and then have a link to see all of them